# C++ std::filesystem::directory_iterator does not iterate over regular files on Android

Tags: android, c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I tried to write a program that renamed certain files on my phone in a certain way, for this I used `std::filesystem`:

```
for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{ start_path })
{
    if (!entry.is_regular_file()) continue;
    //rename entry in some specific way
}
```

and It worked just as expected. However, when I launched the code in Cxxdroid, the `directory_iterator` did not iterate over regular files, only over directories. And when I wrote

```
for(auto entry : directory_iterator{ "/storage/emulated/0/Downloads" })
    std::cout << entry.path() << '\n';
```

it only listed sub-folders, but not the files. Why is that?

Comment: Your app has no files it created itself in those directories.

Comment: Isa wesa bein' sandboxed?

Comment: Which directory was it? Does user which runs this application has read rights to that directory?

Comment: As far as I know, the binary is created somewhere in app's private location (argv[0] = /data/user/0/ru.iiec.cxxdroid/...). If the iterator tries to access the private folder/file, abort() or something like that is called, so I wasn't trying to access inaccessible directories.